# What is the radius of convergence of $S$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose that $S(x) = \sum^{∞}_{k=0}{a_k x^k}$ is a power series such that $|\frac{a_n +1}{a_n}|→ λ > 0 $ as $n → ∞$. What is the radius of convergence of $S$? (The value $∞$ for $λ$ is permitted. You don’t need to justify your answer.)

Answer:

If $|\frac{a_n +1}{a_n}|→ λ > 0 $ then the radius of convergence $R$ equals $R= \lambda^{-1}$, with the convention $∞^{-1}=0$.

Is this correct? It it the answer given in the past paper solutions, but I don't really understand the last part of "with the convention $∞^{-1}=0$".

Comment: Are you sure the word "connection" was used, and not "convention"?

Comment: It must be convention, the solutions were handwritten and I struggled to understand the lecturer's writing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like the actual definition of radius of convergence, and the reciprocal of infinity being zero, is to say that, that series would only converge at x= 0.

Comment: Is what the solution says correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.